# Azure DevOps defining path filter to yml build file

Tags: azure, azure-devops

My project structure is like

```
/AzureStuff/AzureAA/Source/

/AzureStuff/AzureBB/Source/

/AzureStuff/AzureCC/Source/
```

And my build definition:

```
name: $(BuildDefinitionName)
resources:
- repo: self
queue:
  name: AzureBuild
trigger:
  batch: true
  paths:
    include:
    - /AzureStuff/AzureAA/Source/*
steps:
- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: 'Publish Artifact: AzureAA'
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: AzureStuff/AzureAA/Source
    ArtifactName: AzureAA
```

However, when I commit my sources into the /AzureStuff/AzureAA/Source/ my build does not run. Only the builds for BB and CC runs because they do not have path filter. How should I change my path filter to make the AA build work? I am planning on having path filters on every build.

Comment: Did you try without the leading `/`? I.E. `- AzureStuff/AzureAA/Source/*`

Comment: Yes I tried that first but read from some blog that the leading / is needed.

Comment: The leading `/` is not required as per [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/triggers?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#paths). @DanielMann's suggestion is valid, could you post your full build definition please? Also, worth noting CI won't trigger if your commit message contain one of the skip CI commands [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/triggers?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#skipping-ci-for-individual-commits).

Comment: I added the whole build definition. I have used commit messages like "testing" and "asfagsa" but that does not do any change.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

path triggers have to be relative to the root of the repo, just like the [docs mention](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/triggers?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#paths) (and the very first comment):

```
trigger:
  batch: true
  paths:
    include:
    - AzureStuff/AzureAA/Source
```

Comment: How that would translate in my case? I have tried pretty much all the combinations I can think of without success.

Comment: updated to match your case, also, if the repo root is inside the AzureStuff folder, it should be `AzureAA/Source/*`

Comment: Repo root is under that AzureStuff. I changed the path include to "AzureStuff/AzureAA/Source/*" but still no builds.

Comment: you can set it to `- "*"` just to test if it works at all, if it works, means you path glob is wrong, if it doesnt - probably a bug. I'm pretty sure your path glob is wrong

Comment: Ok, that did neither help so it looks like a bug.

Comment: Be really careful about the alignment of the minus signs.  I found that if the minus sign was indented from the word 'include', it would *not* work, but if it was as the same indent column as the word include, it *would* work

Comment: just yaml things. use yaml validators

Comment: Also, `paths` doesn't support wildcards (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/azure-repos-git?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml&WT.mc_id=AZ-MVP-5003781#paths), which tripped me up.

Comment: FYI: Now paths are supporting wildcards (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/azure-repos-git?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml&WT.mc_id=AZ-MVP-5003781#wildcards)

Answer (score 4):

You're missing your branch filter

> When you specify paths, you must explicitly specify branches to trigger on. You can't trigger a pipeline with only a path filter; you must also have a branch filter

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/azure-repos-git?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml&WT.mc_id=AZ-MVP-5003781#paths

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
    - master
  paths:
    include:
    - AzureStuff/AzureAA/Source/
```